# Share work equally in multiple fixed Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, partitioning

I'm making a software in java who factorize a square matrix A in LU : A = LU.
I'm trying to make it *concurrent* with Java Threads.

Every DecomposerThread has a **int start** and **int end** as local variables.

The question is: given two integers **n** (who represent the square matrix length) and **numThr** (who represent a fixed number of thread), what is the loop for instantiate every thread with an (almost) equal number of rows? (The matrix have to be "covered" form 0 to n-1)

Ex: with only one thread

**int start = 0; int end = n-1;**

```
    int numThr = 4, n = 2502;
    int [] pool = new int[numThr];

    int passo = n/numThr;
    int old = passo;

    System.out.println("Start: "+(0)+" end: "+(passo));

    for(int i = 1; i<pool.length; i++){

        System.out.println("Start: "+(old+1)+" end: "+(passo*(i+1) - 1));
        old = (passo*(i+1) - 1);;

    }
```

But the result is:

```
    Start: 0 end: 625
    Start: 626 end: 1249
    Start: 1250 end: 1874
    Start: 1875 end: 2499
```

How you can see, the end value of the last Thread is 2499 instead of **2501**. How could I solve this problem?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n/numThr == 2502/4 == 625 remainder 2
```

All threads get 625 rows, 2 threads get 1 more row too.  My Java is laughable so I'll leave you to code it up

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the current error. This steps through the correct positions - you may need to use +/- 1 in places for your use:

```
public void test() {
  calc(2502, 4);
  calc(5, 4);
}

public void calc(int n, int thr) {
  final int size = n / thr;
  final int err = n % thr;
  int totalErr = 0;
  int start = 0;

  System.out.println("n=" + n + " thr=" + thr + " Size: " + size + " err: " + err);
  for (int i = 0; i < thr; i++) {
    int end = start + size;
    totalErr += err;
    if (totalErr >= thr) {
      end += 1;
      totalErr -= thr;
    }
    System.out.println("Start: " + start + " end: " + end);
    start = end;
  }
}
```

prints

```
n=2502 thr=4 Size: 625 err: 2
Start: 0 end: 625
Start: 625 end: 1251
Start: 1251 end: 1876
Start: 1876 end: 2502
n=5 thr=4 Size: 1 err: 1
Start: 0 end: 1
Start: 1 end: 2
Start: 2 end: 3
Start: 3 end: 5
```

Comment: Yes the % operation is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

A smooth way to iterate through an array (as long as you are only reading) is to have an ongoing index that each Thread reads, then decrements atomically. The benefit is that you do not need to split the array beforehand and you won't artificially force certain threads to be active, while the OS/JVM determines that it should be put on hold for whatever reason.

A possible implementation:

```
float[] matrix = new float[n];
final AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(n);
```

In Thread x:

```
run() {
  int myIndex;
  while ((myIndex = index.decrementAndGet()) >= 0) {
    compute(matrix[myIndex]);
  }
}
```

This approach is about as fast as your approach (since it skips the copy and atomics are very fast), but guarantees that all indexes are eventually processed. And as you can probably see: this approach is far simpler to code compared to other implementations. ;)

Comment: This is a REALLY intelligent solution because my implementation let some threads waiting and reduce the parallelism of the application. An huge thanks you mate!